# Passt zum Verb „entscheiden“ nur die Präposition „gegen“?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob man immer *gegen* für das Verb *entscheiden* benutzt.

> **Beispiel**
>   Manchmal muss man  sich gegen den eigenen Wunsch entscheiden.

Comment: Wenn Du Dich nur dafür entscheidest, kann Du auch was anderes nehmen :-)

Comment: Es kommt darauf an! Geht es um vernünftige Vorschläge, habe ich manchmal das Gefühl, es wäre so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die reflexiven Wendungen lauten

> sich gegen etwas entscheiden (=contra, Akkusativ)
>
> sich entgegen etwas enscheiden (=contra, Genitiv)
>
> sich für etwas entscheiden (=pro)
>
> sich zwischen etwas und etwas anderem entscheiden (Dativ)

Die nicht-reflexiven Wendungen lauten

> etwas entscheiden (Akkusativ)
>
> über etwas entscheiden (Akkusativ)
>
> in etwas entscheiden (Akkusativ)
>
> wider etwas entscheiden (=contra, Akkusativ)
>
> wegen etwas entscheiden (Genitiv)
>
> hinsichtlich etwas entscheiden (Genitiv)

Comment: Vielleicht ist *entscheiden zwischen* auch möglich, ne?

Comment: Ja, und auch "wider", "trotz", "wegen", hinsichtlich", "bei" etc

Comment: "wieder" geht auch, ist allerdings keine Präposition sondern ein Adverb ;-)

Comment: Seit wann verlangt "wider" den Genitiv und nicht den Akkusativ?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Hast Recht, hab ich geändert.

Comment: Das Wort _entgegen_ verlangt den Dativ, nicht den Genitiv. Beispiel: "Ich habe mich entgegen _deinem_ Rat entschieden."

Comment: _entgegen_ passt hier sowieso nicht ganz rein: Ich kann mich genauso _entgegen etwas_ entscheiden, wie ich mich _entgegen etwas_ duschen kann: "Ich habe mich entgegen deinem Rat geduscht."

Comment: @sgf Nein, es gibt einen Unterschied. In deinem Satz "Ich habe mich entgegen deine*s* Rat*es* geduscht." ist `entgegen deines Rates` eine Adverbialbestimmung, die den vollständig verständlichen Restsatz `Ich habe mich geduscht.` lediglich näher beschreibt. In dem Satz "Ich habe mich entgegen deines Vorschlags entschieden." ist `entgegen deines Vorschlags` ein Präpositionalobjekt, da der Restsatz `Ich habe mich entschieden.` nicht vollständig verständlich ist, weil man nicht weiß, wie die Entscheidung lautet.

Comment: @Toscho Das ist genau mein Punkt: _Ich habe mich entgegen deines Vorschlags entschieden._ heißt nur "Ich habe mich entschieden, und das, obwohl du mir etwas anderes geraten hast", nicht "Ich habe mich gegen deinen Vorschlag entschieden." _gegen_ und _entgegen_ sind verschiedene Wörter, und man kann für _Die Römer führen gegen die Gallier Krieg_ auch nicht einfach _Die Römer führen entgegen der Gallier Krieg_ sagen.

Comment: @sgf Du scheinst den Beispielsatz nicht richtig zu verstehen. Du erläuterst ihn als „`Ich habe mich entschieden, und das, obwohl du mir etwas anderes geraten hast`“. So macht der Satz auch wenig Sinn. `du` wird `ich` wohl kaum geraten haben, sich nicht zu entscheiden, wie du es mit diesem Satz ausdrückst. Statt dessen hat er ihm eine Entscheidungsmöglichkeit geraten und `ich` hat aber die andere Möglichkeit gewählt.

Comment: @sgf Und die Präposition eines Präpositionalobjekts eines Verbs auf ein anderes Verb zu übertragen macht keinen Sinn, weil die deutsche Sprache nicht zu  funktioniert.

Comment: @Toscho Aber niemand sagt "Ich entscheide mich entgegen Möglichkeit 2", oder zumindest habe ich noch nie jemanden so etwas sagen oder schreiben hören, bis ich deine Antwort hier gelesen habe, und genau das war mein Punkt: Die einzige Lesart, die für mich bei _entgegen_ hier in Frage kommt, ist die (wie du richtig sagst etwas unsinnige), weil sich entscheiden - meinem Sprachgefühl nach - eben kein Präpositionalobjekt mit _entgegen_ bildet. (Wie, soweit ich weiß, auch kein einziges anderes Verb des Deutschen.)